# regular expression in R to find *****

Tags: regex, r, gsub

what is regular expression for  * * * * *? (no space between *)

```
gsub(pattern = "??", replacement="", txt1)
```

I've done with `[**]*$, [^**]+$, [**]*$`

Comment: Can you describe in words what you want your regular expression to do.  Are you looking for a literal 5 asterisks in a row or do you just want 5 characters in a row?  If you're having trouble figuring out a regular expression for something then when you come to ask for help for it you should try to explain what you want in words and give a few example inputs and your desired output.

Comment: I think you need to read the help page for `?regex`. The answer should have been apparent after some modest amount of effort.

Answer (score 8):

```
> x <- c("** ***", "*****", "***")
> grep("\\*{5}", x, value = TRUE)
## [1] "*****"
```

So one of the possible regular expressions to find five consecutive `*` symbols is `\\*{5}`.

If you wanted to find **all** strings that do not contain a space, the easiest way would be to search for a space and then use the `invert` argument of `grep`.

```
> grep("\\s", x, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
## [1] "*****" "***"
```

Answer (score 8):

Most regex metacharacters can be used in a character class without escaping.  To me it's more readable (and it helps even more if you have something else in the way, interpreting the backslashes).

```
grep('[*]{5}', x, value=TRUE)
```

If this isn't part of another expression, `fixed=TRUE` is quite handy:

```
grep('*****', x, value=TRUE, fixed=TRUE)
```

Comment: Both are useful answers. As is Scriven's.